# Cordova windows share app between different devices

Tags: windows, cordova

Am using cordova to build windows platform. Previously when building for android I would run `cordova build android` and then find the apk file in the build directory and then I can easily share the file amongst different devices.

When building running `cordova build windows` I am finding following files in platform/windows/

```
1.appmanifest.xml
2.cordovaapp.windows.build.appxrecipe
3.resources.pri
```

How do I get the executable file to install in other devices since when running `cordova run windows` the application is successifully launched in my computer.

I have also tried running with visual studio and the same results as above are produced.

Answer (score 0):

After running `cordova build windows` Cordova creates a `.appx` file in a directory like so:

```
platforms\windows\AppPackages\AppName.Windows_1.0.0.0_anycpu_debug_Test
```

where AppName is the name of your app.

---

> APPX is the file format used to distribute and install apps on Windows
>   8.x and 10, Windows Phone 8.1, Windows 10 Mobile, Xbox One, Hololens, and Windows 10 IoT Core.

References: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464929.aspx) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform_apps#APPX)

You can install this `.appx` file on your PC by doubleclicking it. On a Windows 10 mobile device you can follow a tutorial like [this one](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/UWP-Apps-How-to-instal-d20eb116) (just skip the first part on how to create a `.appx`, as you already have one).